# Redirect output of a command to two different files

Tags: shell-script, files, io-redirection

I know I can use tee, but I don't want the output to be printed on the screen; I want it to be printed only to the file.

Example:

```
ls > pk.txt
```

Now, another file named praveen should also be created.

Answer (score 6):

Use `tee(1)` to write to two files and discard stdout:

```
ls | tee pk.txt praveen >/dev/null
```

**Edit2:** As pointed out by Stephane and Thomas, because of how `tee` works, this is a better version and results in less writes:

```
ls | tee pk.txt > praveen
```

Comment: Why prune the `tee` output instead of doing `ls | tee pk.txt > praveen`?

Comment: _"...because of how tee works, this is equivalent to: `ls | tee pk.txt > praveen`"_ Actually, while the _output_ might be equivalent, the former oneliner leads to unnecessary writes in order to discard the output, so the _behavior_ is **not** equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
ls > file1 > file2
```

(internally, `zsh` creates a pipe and spawns a process that reads from that pipe and writes to the two files as `tee` does. `ls` stdout is the other end of the pipe).